# Running APK files directly in the browser

Tags: javascript, android, apk, webassembly

I have seen a way of running Pygame directly with WASM in the browser ([link here](https://pygame-wasm-testing.mna4.repl.co), [files here](https://replit.com/@MNA4/Pygame-WASM-Testing?v=1#project.html)). The weird thing is that it uses an APK file for the actual Pygame code. So it made me wonder if it was possible to run a mobile game APK file in the browser.

I have searched Google but all I have found is running an Android VM on a server.

Is it possible to actually run the APK file directly in the browser?

Comment: It says that it loads apk file, but I don't see a like that would do this here

Comment: apk is kind of like zip and this particular apk have only `main.py` inside, so it probably just loads apk unzips it and compiles python to wasm

Comment: @Konrad yeah, APK is a ZIP file. But would it be possible to run an APK containing an Android mobile game?

Comment: @LuisAFK if someone were to write an Android simulator that would run in a browser